# Use Bash to compare clipboard to a string

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to find out whether the contents of a variable equal a string.

The variable being set:

```
~ myvar=$(pbpaste)
~ echo myvar
"my string"
```

I've tried things like:

```
"my string"==$(myvar)
"my string"==$myvar
if "my string"==$(myvar); then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need to handle the space in the string "my string"

Comment: What does "handle" mean?

Comment: `if [ "my string"=="$myvar" ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi`

Comment: What you posted cannot be true: `echo myvar` must output literally `myvar`, not anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare a variable with a string in bash do:

```
if [[ "my string" == "$myvar" ]]; then
    echo 1;
else
    echo 0;
fi
```

Remember to put quotes around `$myvar` to avoid a syntax error in the case where `$myvar` is empty.

Take a look at [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)